# Selection.Find wildcard results to array

Tags: vba, ms-word

Consider the following macro, that I got from Macro Recorder:

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'
'
      Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
      Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
      With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
            .Bold = True
            .Color = wdColorGreen
      End With
      With Selection.Find
            .Text = "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
      End With
      Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

How could I get all results and save them to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this using `Range` objects. Think of a `Range` as being an invisible selection with the important difference that there can be many ranges, but only one selection.

In the code below the search Range (`rSearch`) is set to the entire document and the `Find` properties are defined for it, rather than `Selection`. I changed `wrap` from `wdFindContinue` to `wdFindStop` so that the macro won't start over from the beginning of the document again, and again, and again... And `wdReplaceAll` needs to be `wdReplaceOne` so that each found range can be processed.

The `Do`-loop is where the assignment of the found range to the array (`aFoundRanges`) takes place. If the search is successful the array is "redimmed" to accept an additional member. The found Range is "duplicated" to the range `rFound`, which is assigned to the array. The counter is incremented; `rFound` is re-set*. The search range is re-set to begin at the end of the last "hit" and end at the end of the document.

This loops until `Find.Execute` is no longer successful.

```
Sub KeepFoundInArray()
'
    Dim rSearch As Word.Range
    Dim rFound As Word.Range
    Dim aFoundRanges() As Word.Range
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    Set rSearch = ActiveDocument.content
    rSearch.Find.ClearFormatting
    rSearch.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With rSearch.Find.Replacement.Font
          .Bold = True
          .color = wdColorGreen
    End With
    With rSearch.Find
          .Text = "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"
          .Replacement.Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .wrap = wdFindStop
          .Format = True
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = False
          .MatchAllWordForms = False
          .MatchSoundsLike = False
          .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Do
        bFound = rSearch.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
        If bFound Then
            ReDim Preserve aFoundRanges(counter)
            Set rFound = rSearch.Duplicate
            Set aFoundRanges(counter) = rFound
            Set rFound = Nothing
            counter = counter + 1
            rSearch.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rSearch.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
        End If
    Loop While bFound
    Debug.Print UBound(aFoundRanges)
End Sub
```

- It's necessary to duplicate the found range - if you don't, that range will be written to the array. And it will always reflect the *current* range rSearch - what the array members "point to" will be that `Range`. A duplicate copies the `Range` object and makes the copy independent of the original. That's also why it's a good idea to re-set `rFound`(`Set rFound = Nothing`) - to ensure the next instance of `rSearch.Duplicate` is again independent.

Comment: Cindy, you, Sir, are a Angel!! I printed the question and your response, I am going to study it so that I can unveil the power and toughness of the Find method. Thank you very very much Sir!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Feel free to ask back if anything in the explanation is unclear.